# Conditional removal of rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a data frame with 2 columns and 26 rows, the first column is composed of characters while the second column is composed of numbers.
I also have a vector with a random selection of 5 characters.

I want to sum the numbers from column two of the 5 random characters.

How can I calculate this sum?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: data1 <- data.frame(char = letters, ints = sample(1:15)) and then there is a sample of sample1<-sample(letters, 5). I want to sum the numbers from column two of the letters in the sample. @akrun

Comment: Please check the solution posted.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(ints ~ char, data1, sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is :

```
result <- sum(data1$ints[data1$char %in% sample1], na.rm = TRUE)
```

This will `sum` the `ints` value in `data1` which is present in `sample1`.